# Does Swiftness stack with Signet of the Hunt?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The latest patch increased the passive effect of Signet of the Hunt from 10% to 25%, which is a noticeable increase of speed. Before the patch, however, I was using 6x Superior Rune of the Centaur, which increases the duration of all swiftness effects by 20% and gives you 10 seconds of swiftness (before the 20%) when you cast a heal.

Since the patch though, I can see the graphical effect for swiftness when I gain it, but I don't seem to be moving any faster than the base movement speed increase I get from Signet of the Hunt.

Does Swiftness stack with Signet of the Hunt?

Comment: Thieves also have a signet that increases move speed by 25% and I can confirm that swiftness _does_ stack with that.  I would be surprised if the other signets worked differently.

Comment: There is a cap on forward movement speed. You will hit this cap with swiftness when you are out of combat

Comment: what is the cap, and how much movement speed increase does swiftness give?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/88775/336

Comment: The highest bonus % speed sticks, so it could just be that the difference from 25% -> 33% isn't nearly as noticeable as when it jumped from 10% -> 33%.

Comment: @pixel Erm. At least 2 of those skills are from Guild Wars 1, not 2.

Comment: who would have known how much of a difference one character in a URL made a difference would make!

Comment: @pixel As a programmer-by-trade, I can safely say that one character can make a helluva a difference all too often. -_-

Comment: that was supposed to be rhetorical! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [speed boosts do NOT stack in Guild Wars 2](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Movement_speed), unlike in Guild Wars 1, which is what the above comments are referencing.